# Make Feature Flag required based on another Feature Flag in Flagsmith

Tags: dependencies, feature-flags, flagsmith

In Flagsmith, is there a way to tie Feature Flags together in a way that if I enable Feature Flag "A", and that requires Feature Flag "B", then the user is warned that Flag "B" is required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm a [Flagsmith](https://flagsmith.com/) founder)

Right now, Flagsmith doesnt have dependent flags. We do have plans to implement them (as of Feb 2024) which you can [track here](https://github.com/Flagsmith/flagsmith/issues/1674).

As a work around, you can achieve dependency in code by writing a helper function that checks the state of Flag A and Flag B.

Having said that, we do generally regard flag dependencies as something of an anti-pattern; it adds complexity and can sometimes obscure the resultant application behaviour.

We do occasionally have folk who present a use case that would help with dependent flags, hence its inclusion on the roadmap.

Comment: The purpose is actually to help PMs know in the Flagsmith UI that if they want to enable Feature Flag A, he also needs to enable Feature Flag B. So, the dependency is just a way to sinalize that those features go together like a Group. And they are different FFs because I could have FF A that depends on FF C and another FF B that depends on FF C, while FF A and FF B are independent of each other. I hope that it makes sense.

Comment: Not really! Are you saying this is just a UI convenience that wouldnt affect the actual flag evaluations? Or would you be able to control the value of flag B by modifying Flag A?

Comment: I would say both. I like to make the parallel to any dependency manager today (nuget, npm, pip,..), where you select a package to install and the system automatically install all dependencies. The user (developer in this case) doesn't need to go on installing each dependency before you can install the package that you want.

Comment: So, coming back to Flagsmith UI, imo the best solution would be to have a way in the system to indicate that Feature A depends on Feature B and that dependency would cause the following behavior: If the user goes to the UI and try to turn on Feature A and Feature B is already enabled, then Feature A just gets enabled. If Feature B is not already enabled, he gets a dialog saying "This Feature A requires Feature B, do you want to enable all of them together?" and if the user click Yes, then the system enables Feature B and Feature A.

Comment: Related discussion here https://github.com/Flagsmith/flagsmith/issues/1674